# One specific Wordpress custom post type not showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

For a Wordpress template I created several custom post types in the functions.php file.
At this moment the post types are showing correct on my MacBook and iPhone when I do the following queries:

Only the specific 'News' post type:

`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news' ); query_posts($args);`

Multiple custom post types:

`$args = array( 'post_type' => array('sponsors','news','teams','businessclub','events') ); query_posts($args);`

The weird thing is, that on several other devices, only the custom post type 'news' is not showing up, the others do in the query with multiple custom post types.

Anybody who can help me out with this strange thing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick the post_type from your first array of `$args` into its own array?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => array('news') ); 
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. The problem wasn't in Wordpress itself, but the Role Scoper plugin prevented the post type from being shown. The fact that I didn't see the posts on other devices had to do with the fact that I wasn't logged in on those. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

This should make it all work. 
Solution found here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page